# Cordova Phonegap HTML5 Sound doesnt work until after I record a video

Tags: ios, html, cordova, audio, video

I cant find the reason for this anywhere.

We have an app where you can record a video and then see other people's recorded videos. If you don't record a video and you just login and try to play other people's videos, the video will play but the audio doesnt.

The moment that you try to record a video and the video camera opens up, if you go back and play any video - the audio starts working. Its the weirdest thing. We're just using HTML5 for the video. It works on Safari, just not on the PhoneGap Developer app or when we compile into a native iOS app.

Here's a the block of HTML that has the video code

```
<video style="box-shadow: 1px 0pc 1pc 1pc rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);z-index: 3626722;max-height: 250px; width: 100%;  border-radius: 8%; max-width: 250px;" controls="" class="vsc-initialized" data-vscid="bjw06681d"><source style="max-height:200px" src="http://18.216.250.32/GoWithMe/media/videos/121.MOV" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

The sound works on Safari, Chrome, just not in Phonegap until you record a video. Any idea's?!